# Jquery: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=someVar]

Tags: jquery, meta

Simple enough code:

```
$("meta[name=DCSext.Level]")
```

Error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=DCSext.Level]
```

I upgraded from 1.4.2 to 1.7.1 in Jquery. It obviously still works in 1.4.2.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax should be `[name="DCSext.Level"]` as specified in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). I recommend using single quotes for strings in JS so that you don't have to escape double-quotes, which I prefer to use for HTML:

```
$('meta[name="DCSext.Level"]')
```

Although you could continue to use double quotes:

```
$("meta[name=\"DCSext.Level\"]");
```

And you could swap the quote usage:

```
$("meta[name='DCSext.Level']");
```

---

This all of course assumes that the attribute itself is as follows:

```
<meta name="DCSext.Level" ... />
```

If DCSext is a JS object, you'll need to concatenate it into the string:

```
$('meta[name="' + DCSext.Level + '"]');
```

Comment: humm embarrassing that even whilst looking at the api doc's i didn't notice the quotes round the name ;) cheers

Comment: and they take so long to fix.. :p for instance having to start a thread on the problem

Answer (score 3):

You should add quotes if it is string:

```
$("meta[name='DCSext.Level']")
```

Or if it is variable:

```
$("meta[name='" + DCSext.Level + "']")
```

Answer (score 1):

or if DCSext.Level is a variable:

```
$('meta[name="' + DCSext.Level + '"]');
```

Comment: its not a var but the quotes around the name='as' is what i needed